# Android - Adding Subitem to Sorted ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, sorting, subitem

I have the following code for a ListView:

```
private class CollegeItem {
private double gpa;
private int act;
private int sat;
private String name;
private String location;
private double score;
private boolean match;
private double scoreDistance;


private boolean uaero, uagri, ubio, uchem, ucivil, ucomp, uelec, uphys, uenvi, uindus, umate, umech;

public CollegeItem(double gpa, int act, int sat, String name, String location, boolean uaero, boolean uagri, boolean ubio, boolean uchem,
                    boolean ucivil, boolean ucomp, boolean uelec, boolean uphys, boolean uenvi, boolean uindus, boolean umate, boolean umech){
    this.gpa = gpa;
    this.act = act;
    this.sat = sat;
    this.name = name;
    this.location = location;
    this.uaero = uaero;
    this.uagri = uagri;
    this.ubio = ubio;
    this.uchem = uchem;
    this.ucivil = ucivil;
    this.ucomp = ucomp;
    this.uelec = uelec;
    this.uphys = uphys;
    this.uenvi = uenvi;
    this.uindus = uindus;
    this.umate = umate;
    this.umech = umech;

    if(act/36.0>sat/2400.0){
        this.score = 0.6*gpa*25.0+0.4*(act/36.0)*100.0;
    }else{
        this.score = 0.6*gpa*25.0+0.4*(sat/2400.0)*100.0;
    }
    scoreDistance = Math.abs(this.score-MainActivity.scoreDouble)/MainActivity.scoreDouble;
    if(uagri&&ListOfMajors.agricultural||uchem&&ListOfMajors.chem||uaero&&ListOfMajors.aerospace||ubio&&ListOfMajors.biomed||ucivil&&ListOfMajors.civil
            ||ucomp&&ListOfMajors.computer||uelec&&ListOfMajors.electrical||uphys&&ListOfMajors.physics||uenvi&&ListOfMajors.environment||uindus&&ListOfMajors.industrial
            ||umate&&ListOfMajors.materials||umech&&ListOfMajors.mechanical){
        scoreDistance--;
    }else{
        scoreDistance = Math.abs(this.score-MainActivity.scoreDouble)/MainActivity.scoreDouble;
    }
}

ArrayList<CollegeItem> collegeLists=new ArrayList<CollegeItem>();
ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();

Comparator<CollegeItem> compare = new Comparator<CollegeItem>(){
    public int compare(CollegeItem a, CollegeItem b){
            return Double.compare(a.getScoreDistance(), b.getScoreDistance());
    }
};
 Collections.sort(collegeLists, compare);

    for(CollegeItem collegeList : collegeLists){
        nameList.add(collegeList.getName());
    }

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(CollegeList.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nameList));
```

As of right now, the order of the ListView is in ascending order of the field variable scoreDistance. It is sorted this way through the comparator. The actual content of the List is the field variable name. I would now like to add the field variable location as a subitem for each name. It should still be sorted the same way. I have looked at multiple questions regarding adding subitems but am still unsure how to do this. What should I do?

Comment: you should create a custom adapter

Comment: How would I do that while still keeping the order of elements the same?

Comment: the adapter does not sort the items for you. So if you sort those, they will be shown in the same order

Comment: I am new to adapters so could you please provide sample code?